# RecyclerView item align left

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `tags_frame` in the `FoodCardFragment` (whose layout can be found [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_food_card.xml)) that is used for displaying a `RecyclerView` in the [`TagsFragment`](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/java/personalprojects/seakyluo/randommenu/TagsFragment.java). The layout of `TagsFragment` is simply:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />
```

The `RecyclerView` uses either `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` or `LinearLayoutManager`. However, as you can see from the middle of my cardview, this `RecyclerView` (composed of round-corner rectangles) uses `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` and it is centered. And actually in another activity I used `LinearLayoutManager` it is also centered.

How can I align it to the left (start) of the card?

[image]

Comment: Post the code in your question instead of linking to it.

Comment: Try to change layout_width in ConstraintLayout to 320dp or wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your `fragment_tags.xml`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />
```

Use `wrap_content` for `layout_width`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are constraint your FrameLayout to parent on both sides and set width as match_parent. You have more options, One is to set gravity start to your framelayout or set width of the framelayout as wrap_content and constraint only to start.